# Cannot use object of type MDWEB\In English Bundle\Entity\InEnglish as array Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

I encountered this error and I did not understand how to fix it.
the error occurs here:  `unset($inenglish[$count]);`

```
public function findAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $listEnglishs = $em->getRepository('MDWEBInEnglishBundle:InEnglish')->findBy(array('deleted' => 0,'activated'=>1), array('createdAt' => 'DESC'));
    $tags=$em->getRepository('MDWEBActualiteBundle:Tag')->findAll();
    $categories=$em->getRepository('MDWEBActualiteBundle:Categorie')->findBy(array('deleted' => 0, 'activated' => 1));
    $years = range(date('Y'), 2000);
    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $year=$request->request->get('annee');
        $categorie=$request->request->get('categorie');
        $tag=$request->request->get('tag');
        $count=0;

        foreach($listEnglishs as $inenglish){
            foreach($tags as $t) {

                $t->getId();

           if ($inenglish->getCategorie()->getId()!=$categorie && date('Y',strtotime($inenglish->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d')))!=$year && $t->getId()!=$tag ) {
                unset($inenglish[$count]);
            }
            $count++;
        }}
    }
    return $this->render('MDWEBFrontBundle:InEnglish:list.html.twig',array(
        'listEnglishs' => $listEnglishs,
        'categories'=>$categories,
        'tags'=>$tags,
        'years'=>$years
    ));
}
```

Comment: Unless $inenglish is an array when you access it here: foreach($listEnglishs as $inenglish){ then I think that's where the error is coming from when you attempt this: unset($inenglish[$count]);
Using the [] means that you're trying to access $inenglish as an array.

Comment: yes thanks , this is the solution $listEnglishs[$count]